# Optimizing my query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, optimization

Here's my query:

```
DECLARE @monthStartDate date;
DECLARE @monthEndDate date;
    
SET @monthStartDate = DATEFROMPARTS(2020,6,1);
SET @monthEndDate = EOMONTH(@monthStartDate);
     
SELECT @monthStartDate, MIN([Date]), @monthEndDate, GroupId, TypeId,
    COUNT(UserID) as 'CountTotal',
    SUM(CASE WHEN [IsA] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'CountA',
    SUM(CASE WHEN [IsB] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'CountB',
    SUM(CASE WHEN [IsC] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'CountC',
    SUM(CASE WHEN [IsEven] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'CountEven',
    SUM(CASE WHEN [IsOdd] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'CountOdd',
    SUM(CASE WHEN [IsEven] = 1 AND [IsA] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'CountAEven',
    SUM(CASE WHEN [IsOdd] = 1 AND [IsA] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'CountAOdd',
    SUM(CASE WHEN [IsEven] = 1 AND [IsC] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'CountCEven',
    SUM(CASE WHEN [IsOdd] = 1 AND [IsC] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'CountCOdd',
    SUM(CASE WHEN [IsEven] = 1 AND [IsB] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'CountBEven',
    SUM(CASE WHEN [IsOdd] = 1 AND [IsB] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'CountBOdd'
FROM MyTable
WHERE [Date] >= @monthStartDate AND [Date] <= @monthEndDate
GROUP BY [Date], GroupId, TypeId
ORDER BY Date, GroupId, TypeId
```

which selects from this table:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [MyTable](
    [UserID] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [GroupId] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
    [IsEven] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsOdd] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [TypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsA] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsB] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsC] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Http_Uniques] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Date] DESC,
    [GroupId] ASC,
    [UserID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [MyTable]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_MyTable_Period] CHECK  (([IsIn]<>(0) OR [IsOut]<>(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [MyTable] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_MyTable_Period]
GO
```

It works, but the table is going to have millions of rows eventually, and I'm obviously cautious about performances.

Do you see a way to optimize this query? Thanks.

Comment: [Yet Another Post About Local Variables](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/2020/03/yet-another-post-about-local-variables/)

Comment: [UserID] [varchar](32) looks like you actually use GUID for UserID (with omitted "-"). You can reduce table size changing data type.

Comment: @ErikDarling so local variables in SP are a bad idea; should I just use the functions themselves in my SELECT instead?

Comment: @Nikita It is indeed an altered GUID, but I cannot change what I'm receiving

Comment: @Kilazur you should pass clear predicates to your query. Putting functions in your where clause doesn't do much to increase transparency.

Answer (score 4):

If you're attempting to optimize aggregation queries inside SQL Server, the single best tool you can put to work is Columnstore indexes. They are specifically built to handle aggregation of exactly this type of data. This is especially true when we're talking millions of rows of data or more.

The original question doesn't say what version of SQL Server you're running, but if you're on 2016 or greater, you can realize the best possible use of your storage and your indexing. If the majority of the queries against your table are analytical in nature, you can store the table as a clustered columnstore. Then, you can add nonclustered indexes in support of point lookups. If, on the other hand, you're still seeing primarily OLTP queries, with only the occasional analytical query, you can add a nonclustered columnstore to a table stored as a clustered index. You can read more about [picking the right columnstore index here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-design-guidance?view=sql-server-ver15).

Because the initial implementation of columnstore indexes was less than ideal, they were read only at first, many people have dismissed them from their tool box. However, you're looking at exactly the kind of query they're meant to solve. Test it. Guaranteed you'll see a massive improvement in query performance, even with the use of local variables (which, by the way, was already pointed out to you, can, sometimes, cause performance issues because of how they affect row estimates, in many cases, a parameter value or a hard-coded value may perform better because you'll get a better plan due to better row estimates).

Comment: I looked into columnstore indexes a few days ago, and the fact that they were read only was a deal breaker, since this table will receive new data regularly. Are you telling me columnstores aren't read only anymore?

Comment: @Kilazur It depends on your version.  Clustered columnstore indexes allow updates in 2014 and higher, nonclustered columnstore indexes allow updates in 2016 and higher.

Comment: @JoshDarnell Yeah, I didn't understand properly. Read-only here doesn't mean I can't insert new rows, which is what I need. I will probably never need to update or delete anything (outside of initial tests), so that seems like a way to go regardless of my version of SQL Server.

Comment: Yep, columnstore indexes can be inserted/updated/deleted, live, in real time, no big deal. The write-once version is 8 years old. All newer version of SQL Server support updates.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing on these fields would be key:
[Date], GroupId, TypeId

However, whatever date ranges are "typical" for your query, I would set up partitions for that size.  Ie, if you are typically querying for a month of data and you set up a partition by month, you will only look at a single parittion (ie, the rows for that month), no matter how much data you have.  The optimizer will choose the partition if it's partitioned on the same field.  10 rows or 100M, you will see hte same/similar performance.

Comment: I will indeed always work on monthly sets of data, partitioning seems like a good idea.

Comment: As long as your queries support partition elimination. As soon as you're querying in a way that doesn't allow for partition elimination, performance radically degrades to begin worse than a monolithic table.

Comment: Thanks Grant.  That is a very important part I forgot to call out.  As always review your actual execution plan to ensure you are getting what you hope for from the query.